# Eslint Vue Plugin

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint

My project is also using the eslint vue plugin. My rules are as follows.

```
"rules": {
        "vue/html-closing-bracket-newline": ["error", {
            "singleline": "never",
            "multiline": "always"
        }],
        "vue/html-closing-bracket-spacing": "error",
        "vue/max-attributes-per-line": ["error", {
            "singleline": 5,
            "multiline": {
                "max": 1,
                "allowFirstLine": false
            }
        }],
        "quotes": ["error", "single"],
        "eqeqeq": ["error", "always"],
        "no-else-return": ["error", { allowElseIf: false }],
        "no-eval": "error",
        "no-script-url": "error",
        "no-useless-return": "error",
        "no-multiple-empty-lines": ["error", { max: 1 }],
        "arrow-body-style": ["error", "as-needed"],
        "no-var": "error",
        "object-shorthand": "error",
        "prefer-arrow-callback": "error",
        "object-curly-spacing": ["error", "always"],
        "vue/no-use-v-if-with-v-for": "warn",
        "vue/padding-line-between-blocks": ["error", "always"],
        "vue/require-direct-export": "error",
        "vue/require-name-property": "warn",
        "vue/v-on-function-call": ["error", "never"],
    }
```

When I run lint-fix according to these rules

[image]

this gives errors. But I have corrected both of these problems within my components. What is the reason it still gives these errors?

Comment: Did you restart your local application as well?

Comment: I'm trying it. @SMAKSS

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't work. @SMAKSS

Answer (score 0):

Those are not eslint issues, those are "no rule found" issue, which is more likely something related to a package not being installed or used.

In your eslint config, you should have something on these lines:

```
module.exports = {
  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/recommended',
    '@vue/standard'
  ],
  rules: {
    // examples of vue rule
    'vue/keyword-spacing': 'warn',
  }
}
```

Make sure you have

```
"@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^5.1.0",
"eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2"
```

Comment: It did not solve my problem. But I somehow found a solution. Thank you.

Comment: Which is the solution? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I changed the rules. Then the package.I added "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2" to the JSON file.

Comment: Which is literally what I suggested :)

Comment: Thank you :) @CristianoSoleti